# Sony TV - Not connecting to Internet

Tags: networking, router, hub

I'm not sure if this is the right forum for this, but it's a networking question.

I have in my basement a router (DLink DIR-655) which is connecting to our ISP, and I have cables running to wall jacks in the first floor.  A wall jack which terminates in the living room I have connected to a switch, a DLink 10/100/1000 (DGS-1005G).  To this I have my PS3 connected which can connect to the internet fine (although it seems to not get the same upload / download speeds other devices get) and my Sony Bravia TV (KDL-46Z5100).  The PS3 registers as GB, while the TV 100MB (its port lights orange).

The problem is I can't get the TV to connect to the internet.  If I try DHCP, it doesn't seem to find the DNS server (on another switch connected to the same router in a different room).  If I hard code the IP address, still nothing.

I found that if I connect the TV directly into the wall, it can connect.  It's just through the switch I'm having problems.  Additionally, even if I then plug it back into the switch and connect the switch to the wall jack, the connect continues to work.  It just seems that I can't get it initialize when connected to the switch.

Comment: Change the network cable, or use the cable from your PS3 to connect TV to hub.

Comment: DGS-1005G is not HUB - it's switch. Major difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your DGS-1005G does NOT have a link established to your DIR-655.

The reason why your PS3 still works, because it's using Wi-Fi connection, even when you have connected it using cable, it falls over to Wi-Fi.

The reason why link between your switch and router is not getting established is wrong wiring.
In some cases you cannot connect two switched devices with a the regular wiring.
You need to re-do wiring to match crossover type:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: If you look at the specification for the switch you will find the line All UTP Ports support Auto-MDI/MDI-X, no cross-over cable needed. This means even if you plug in a crossover cable the switch will auto configure around it.I would suggest you plug something else into the switch to test the connection.

Comment: Never trusted Auto-MDIs, happened many times that some models of D-link supported MDI only on WAN port.

Comment: The hub is supposed to auto MDI/MDIX on all ports, and my laptop always worked fine through it.  However, I did discover when I looked at my cabling again that I was in fact using a crossover cable for the PS3.  I replaced the normal cable to the tv with a crossover and it seems to be working now.  What baffles me is that I had tested this setup with I first put the Ethernet ports into the living room, and the TV worked fine with a normal cable. I guess I discovered the PS3 wasn't.

Comment: I have a question about the solution; instead of using two crossover cables from the switch to the devices, can I use two straight cables and use the crossover from the switch to the wall jack?

Comment: @Andy: You got it. That's how it supposed to be in the first place. Switch to Switch - cross, Switch to Device - straight.

Comment: Thanks Radio; one last question if I may.  Why does my server and workstation work when all the cables are straight through?  They are on the exact same model of switch.  Its actually the exact same setup, just in a different room with different devices at the endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue where my TV used to connect but something happened and it stopped. After wracking my brain I unplugged the TV and my router for a minute. After plugging in everything worked so, I guess the TV needed a hard reboot.